# UIDatePicker with white background on item

Tags: ios, ios7, uidatepicker

I have this issue on iOS 7 with UIDatePicker. When I show a UIDatePicker in any view controller it gets a white background on the current date which will disappear if you roll the widget. I've tested with an empty new project with the same result (just new project, set the storyboard color to other than white color and drag any UIDatePicker to the scene and try like this). 
Does anybody know why is this behaviour? This control is supposed to be transparent and not have this white tag with it.
[image]

Comment: Did you resolved this issue? I am having the same problem here and can't find an answer... I'm creating a Universal app, and on the iphone it works fine, but on the iPad it has this problem...

Comment: No I didn't. I filed a bug, #15719124, to Apple's radar but the only response I've had from them is I needed to update my bug report to include a project with an example. That was a week ago and no response till then. Clearly it seems like date picker's bug but it's pretty annoying

Comment: Please update this issue here when you have a response from Apple...this bug is annoying me as well and I need to distribute my app soon...Thanks!

Comment: Two months later and still no information from Apple... I think they are trying to force us to put this control over white backgrounds to avoid this crap

Comment: Hi Rodrigo, I m facing same problem so is it solve?

Comment: No. As far as I know, Apple hasn't pronounce about this bug more than asking me for a test project

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same bug for the iPad version of the app. Somehow, the iPhone version was working fine. I found a workaround to remove the white background from the `UIDatePicker`.

---

#### Observation

- The white background was showing for the first date and the date below it.
- On changing the date (rolling), the white background would go away and would not come again.

---

#### Fix

To solve this problem, before showing the `UIDatePicker` in the view, I manually changed the date once and then re-set the date which is to be shown like this:

```
[datePicker setDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:NSTimeIntervalSince1970]];
[datePicker setDate:[NSDate date]];
//Now add the datepicker to the view that you want to.
```

This seems to remove the annoying white background for me. Tell me if it works for you!

Comment: Thanks! Works for me in iOS 7.1. Just needed to add some interval (in my case 19.5 month work) to date and then set it back again: NSDate date1 = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:60*60*24*30*19.5 sinceDate:date]; [self.startDatePicker setDate:date1 animated:NO]; [self.startDatePicker setDate:date animated:NO];

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem myself. To fix it you need to take a `UIView` object and place it down where you want your `UIDatePicker` to be. Set the Background color for the `UIView` to White and make sure Opaque is Selected.

Next put your `UIDatePicker` inside of the `UIView` and connect any outlets or anything that needs to be connected with your `UIDatePicker`, from here run your Application and it should work.

Comment: Sooo... your answer is 'make the datepicker white'? The OP and I both have a need for a transparent datepicker so that's not really an adequate answer

Comment: @RedNightingale I had a chat with DTS and they know that it is a know bug that should be fixed in a Xcode Update. At this point you have to put a white background behind it. Sorry.

Comment: Haha... no worries... I was just looking at your answer and scratching my head ;). Assuming the 'XCode Update' will be the 7.1 GM at this stage

Comment: Only One can Hope! :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a little tricky solution, but solution :) So it is the same problem as with UITableViewCell background color for iPad (iOS 7). The solution:

```
- (void)makeAllSubviewsBackroundClear:(UIView*)view
{
    for (UIView *subview in view.subviews)
    {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
        {
            subview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        }

        [self makeAllSubviewsBackroundClear:subview];
    }
}

-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    [self makeAllSubviewsBackroundClear:self.datePicker];

    [super layoutSubviews];
}
```

The solution is to set "cell" background color to color you need, in our case - clear color, when the cell "appears". Maybe thats not an ideal solution, but I'll hope it will be helpful.

P.S.: you can refactor this code in someway to not call this method in every layout subviews but in special case.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with buggy background and solved it by resolving autolayout constraints. I assume UIDatePicker does not like it when it's constraints conflict with it's intrinsic content size. Try updating constraints in a way that your picker can resize itself to it's contents.