# ios 7 datePicker with unwanted white background on item, possible bug

Tags: ios, ios7, uidatepicker

I have a datepicker and set the background to green.

```
myDatePicker.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```

then when I run the code there is a white background on the item, although I didn't touch any thing on the settings of datepicker. (see the image below).

[image]

I also saw some thread that there is a bug on datepicker with ios 7. Is this true?

Comment: Have you tried with set other backGroundColor of DatePicker ?

Comment: what do you mean? set it with another color? [UIColor redColor]??

Comment: show it https://github.com/rajkumarchalla/DatePickerWithDate

Answer (score 1):

I had the same bug for the iPad version of the app. Somehow, the iPhone version was working fine. I found a workaround to remove the white background from the `UIDatePicker`.

---

#### Observation

- The white background was showing for the first date and the date below it.
- On changing the date (rolling), the white background would go away and would not come again.

---

#### Fix

To solve this problem, before showing the `UIDatePicker` in the view, I manually changed the date once and then re-set the date which is to be shown like this:

```
[datePicker setDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:NSTimeIntervalSince1970]];
[datePicker setDate:[NSDate date]];
//Now add the datepicker to the view that you want to.
```

This seems to remove the annoying white background for me. Tell me if it works for you!

Comment: Thanks! Works for me in iOS 7.1. Just needed to add some interval (in my case 6 months 60*60*24*30*6) to date and then set it back again: NSDate date1 = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:60*60*24*30*6 sinceDate:date]; [self.startDatePicker setDate:date1 animated:NO]; [self.startDatePicker setDate:date animated:NO];

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found a little tricky solution, but solution :) So it is the same problem as with UITableViewCell background color for iPad (iOS 7). The solution:

```
- (void)makeAllSubviewsBackroundClear:(UIView*)view
{
    for (UIView *subview in view.subviews)
    {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
        {
            subview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        }

        [self makeAllSubviewsBackroundClear:subview];
    }
}

-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    [self makeAllSubviewsBackroundClear:self.datePicker];

    [super layoutSubviews];
}
```

The solution is to set "cell" background color to color you need, in our case - clear color, when the cell "appears". Maybe thats not an ideal solution, but I'll hope it will be helpful.

P.S.: you can refactor this code in someway to not call this method in every layout subviews but in special case.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why Apple would do that, but try setting all the subviews to clear color, then set the background to green

```
for (UIView *view in myDatePicker.subviews) {
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
myDatePicker.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this, but it didn't change the white background. is there any other way for this?

Comment: I couldn't replicate your white background issue. Are you using a regular UIDatePicker and not a subclass? Just tried with a fresh project with iOS7.1 and 7.0 simulator, the white label never appears.

Comment: yes Im sure its a UIDatepicker. and here's the weird part, If I ran it on iphone there's none white background only on iPad. so I suggest to try ran and build with iPad. thanks you BTW.

Answer (score 0):

I have this bug too. It seems to be an iOS bug and iOS 7.1 doesn't fix it
It's the same bug as this one : [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20747970/uidatepicker-with-white-background-on-item)